# ¿Cómo normalizar String en Java sin que los acentos se cambien por la letra "a"?

Tags: java, string

Tengo un problema, estoy intentando normalizar un texto y para esto he creado un método que normalice cada palabra. Al hacerlo, este me cambia las letras con acento por la letra a.

Ej: **"canción" = "cancian".**

Este método es llamado dentro de otro de la misma clase en el cual leo desde un archivo de texto, y cada palabra la normalizo y la meto dentro de un ArrayList. Cuando llamo el metodo desde fuera funciona correctamente, pero cuando lo aplico dentro del otro metodo es cuando pasa esto.

He probado con:

```
.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")
```

Y con:

```
replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
```

Y no hay manera, aquí dejo el código del método.

Gracias de antemano.

```
    public static String normalizaString(String plbr) {

    String limpio =null;
    if (plbr !=null) {
        limpio = plbr;
        // Normalizar texto para eliminar acentos, dieresis, cedillas y tildes
        limpio = Normalizer.normalize(limpio, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        // Quitar caracteres no ASCII.
        limpio = limpio.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
        // Poner en minusculas.
        limpio = limpio.toLowerCase();
  //      limpio = limpio.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
        // Quitar cualquier tipo de puntuación aderida a la palabra
        limpio = limpio.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}","");            
    }
    return limpio;
}
```

El método desde el cual hago la llamada es el siguiente:

```
    public static ArrayList<String> fileToArray(String pathText) throws IOException  {

    ArrayList<String> arrayText = new ArrayList<String>();
    String s1;
    String s2;

    // Cargamos el buffer con el contenido del archivo
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (pathText));

    // Leemos la primera linea
    while (br.ready()) {
        s1 = br.readLine();

   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (s1);
    // bucle por todas las palabras
        while (st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            s2 = st.nextToken();
            s2 = HerramientasTexto.normalizaString(s2);
            arrayText.add(s2);
        }       
    }
    //Aqui unicamente muestro por pantalla.
    for (int i =0; i<arrayText.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(arrayText.get(i));
    }
    return arrayText;   
}
```

Comment: Probando tu método, regresa **cancion** no **cancian**. Hace lo que buscas, eliminar los acentos.

Comment: Este método es llamado dentro de otro de la misma clase en el cual leo desde un archivo de texto, y cada palabra la normalizo y la meto dentro de un ArrayList. Cuando llamo el metodo desde fuera funciona correctamente, pero cuando lo aplico dentro del otro metodo es cuando pasa esto

Comment: De acuerdo. Entonces deberías editar tu pregunta, exponiendo ese punto.

Comment: Muchas gracias YemisiSCG, ya está editado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema esta en la lectura del archivo, debes añadir la codificación (e.g. **“UTF-8”**) para que haga la lectura correcta en archivos con tildes en su contenido.

Ya que, al leer el archivo sin ninguna codificación obtiene "canciÃ³n" (en este caso), entonces cuando normaliza resulta "cancian".

Por lo tanto, remplaza la linea donde cargas el Buffer:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (pathText));
```

Por esta:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(pathText), "utf-8"));
```

Con esto en la lectura del archivo se obtendrá "canción" y al normalizar resultará "cancion".

Comment: Sencillamente maravilloso, dios te pague.

Comment: Hola, yo estoy teniendo el mismo problema solo pude corregir lo de los simbolos raros que aparecen, en mi caso las Ñ, en el archivo ya se ve bien, pero en bd los cambia, saben que solución se podría dar? uso oracle